# Even after formatting SD card it shows This memory card cannot be used error in the camera screen

Tags: nikon, memory-card, error, nikon-d3400

My nikon d3400 shows This memory card cannot be used. Card may be damaged. Insert another card. The error shows after taking one or two photos. I formatted in the camera but still the error shows. I formatted in computer but still no help. It is toshiba 16GB SDHC. In computer I did fat32 file system format. The error shows after taking one or two photos.

Comment: This question is very similar to yours, maybe it helps? [What can I do when my Nikon D5200 gives an SD card error with every card?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/60888)

Comment: It is better to format the card in the camera.  If it shows the error, you see it immediately.  If not, it is probably OK.  Memory cards are cheap, so if you have any doubts, get a new one and carry a spare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The card is defective. Throw it away and get a new one.

Even if you could make it work, it could no longer be relied upon.

Comment: Bought new one working fine till now

Comment: The card can be used on other devices viz. other brands of cameras, laptops etc. It could just be a random compatibility issue, however keep in mind that it is somewhat risky. I noticed this happening with 64gb Samsung micro-sd cards that come with SDHC adaptor - but never with standard SDHC of any major brands. The cards that don't work on my Nikon d750 work just fine on my d800e.